How can I make a fixed CSS element stay within the boundaries of its parent without overflowing?
I have a full-page layout with a sticky footer at the bottom. Within this layout, there’s a vertical white separator that spans the entire height of the content area, which works perfectly.
Additionally, I have a fixed-position red separator that covers 50% of the content height, and that also functions as intended. However, I want the red separator to be hidden when scrolling to the bottom of the page, just like the white line, so it doesn’t extend beyond the content area.
I've tried several approaches, including nesting the fixed element inside an absolutely positioned container and applying overflow: hidden; to the content area, but the red line continues to overflow.
Is there a way to achieve this solely with HTML and CSS?

include some codes!

Man - atleast write some code.

To make a fixed CSS element stay within the boundaries of its parent without overflowing, you can use a combination of CSS properties. Here's a short code example that demonstrates how to achieve this:
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
    <div class="white-separator"></div>
    <div class="red-separator"></div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">Sticky Footer</footer>

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevent overflow from body */
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Allow vertical scrolling */
}

.white-separator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%; /* Center it */
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
}

.red-separator {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%; /* Center it */
    width: 2px;
    height: 50%; /* 50% of the content height */
    background: red;
    top: 50%; /* Center it vertically */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    pointer-events: none; /* Prevent interaction */
}

.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
}

For further guidance, you may want to check the solution that a developer has posted on AskFullStack, which also addresses similar issues with fixed elements and scrolling behavior.
